# Docker DIND unable to access private registry

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

I am using GitLab along with GitLab runner and DIND.

Configuration details:

```
---------------------------------------

docker run --privileged --name gitlab-dind -d --restart=always docker:17.07-dind

---------------------------------------

cat gitlab_runner.sh
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
  -v /mnt/data/gitlab/gitlab-runner:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  --link gitlab-dind:docker \
  gitlab/gitlab-runner:v9.5.0

---------------------------------------

cat /mnt/data/gitlab/gitlab-runner/config.toml
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "RunnerA"
  url = "https://gitlab.dev.abc.net"
  token = "d8ed43a69ebed74ccab2493857d8cb"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:17.07"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    host = "tcp://gitlab-dind:2375"
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]

---------------------------------------

cat ~/wksp/test-proj/.gitlab-ci.yml
image: docker.artifactory.abc.net/docker:17.07

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375

# This before_script block was added later but it seems this block
# isn't executed before the DIND tries fetching image from Artifactory
before_script:
  - docker login -u svc-art-user -p some-pwd docker.artifactory.abc.net
  - docker info

services:
- docker.artifactory.abc.net/docker:17.07-dind

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - docker build -t my-docker-node-image .

---------------------------------------
```

As an aside, in the above configuration, is `DOCKER_HOST` config needed in `.gitlab-ci.yml` or just the entry (`host = "tcp://gitlab-dind:2375`) in `config.toml` suffice?

Now when the runner runs, i get the following error:

```
Runner log error:
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.5.0 (413da38)
  on RunnerA (d8ed43a6)
Using Docker executor with image docker.artifactory.abc.net/docker:17.07 ...
Starting service docker.artifactory.abc.net/docker:17.07-dind ...
Pulling docker image docker.artifactory.abc.net/docker:17.07-dind ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: Get https://docker.artifactory.abc.net/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I may be wrong but it seems this error is because the *service account* (`svc-art-user`) isn't able to login *before* the DIND image pull happens.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide authentication details to your Gitlab Runner because it needs to pull the image.

You need to create `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` secret variable with the authentication details as below

```
{
     "auths": {
         "docker.artifactory.abc.net": {
             "auth": "bXlfdXNlcm5hbWU6bXlfcGFzc3dvcmQ="
         }
     }
 }
```

This you can get by logging into docker locally and and checking `~/.docker/config.json`

The documentation provides good details on this

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-an-image-from-a-private-docker-registry

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#using-a-private-container-registry

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry but i forgot to mention that i've already tried this. I copied the content of the config.json (which got generated after i ran the `docker login -u svc-art-user -p some-pwd docker.artifactory.abc.net` command on the host) _as is_ into the `Secret Variable` section of my project setting. Still, the error persists. I hope i don't have to restart the containers. All (GitLab, Runner & DIND) containers are running on one host.

Comment: Try restarting the Gitlab runner because I am not sure if it picks up this variable on start or at run-time

Comment: Even after restart of both runner and docker-dind, the issue persists. :(

Comment: I think this will not work. I guess i'll have to embed `docker login ...` command into the `docker:17.07-dind` image. Will check and confirm.

Comment: I think what i thought was not correct because we want to fetch the `docker:17.07-dind` image from Artifactory so customizing the image itself will not help. So i tried customizing (with `docker login...` and ca.crt) the `docker:17.07` image mentioned in the `image:` section of `.gitlab-ci.yml` file but still getting the same error.

Comment: Do a `docker exec -it gitlab-runner sh` inside the runner and execute your login command and see if it helps

Comment: Login command doesn't work inside the container because it's unable to find docker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155823/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-technext).